How to set an inputSignal of a component from a directive
I wanted to create a directive that sets an inputSignal of a component, when it's used together, but I was not able to.
@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{content()}}`,
})
export class MyComponent {
  public readonly content = input<string | undefined>(undefined, {
    alias: 'my-component',
  });
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-component][withPredefinedContent]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  private readonly component = inject(MyComponent, { host: true });
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.component.content.set(`I can't do this`); // <-- I can't do this. ⭕
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MyComponent, MyDirective],
  template: `
    <div my-component="Text from input"><div>
    <div my-component withPredefinedContent><div>
  `,
})
export class App {}

With a setter @Input I could do it, but I'd like to use the new signal approach as it would(?!) require less code.
Any idea how could I achieve this or a function similar to this?
I have a Stackblitz example

you can't do it with input cause it's non-writable, but you could use model instead. see more info here

Yeah, it works with model but it indicates that the component itself could change the value, but it's not the case.

We should use a model instead of input since the latter does not have a set method.
import {
  Component,
  Directive,
  input,
  AfterContentInit,
  inject,
  signal,
  model,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{content()}}`,
})
export class MyComponent {
  public readonly content = model<string | undefined>(undefined);
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-component][withPredefinedContent]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyDirective {
  private readonly component = inject(MyComponent, { host: true });
  constructor() {
    this.component.content.set(`I can't do this`);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MyComponent, MyDirective],
  template: `
    <div my-component withPredefinedContent [content]="'can do this'"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I've edited the question, so it's clear that I need it both ways to use it.

@Totati input does not have set method, so I cannot force set it, instead use model

@Totati I understand what you want to do, but directive is not the correct approach, go for inheritance where the base class will contain all the configurations and the component will inherit all the default configurations stackblitz but we need to create different component instances.
